# How to return the result set of sequelize query in camel case fashion?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have defined a table schema in the database in an underscored fashion but I want to return the result set API response in camel case fashion. I know I can process the underscored object returned by sequelize and convert it into camelcase fashion. Is there any functionality to return the response of a query in camelcase fashion in sequelize itself?

Comment: Can you please share your model spinet or example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To archieve this you need to use `field` when defining your model.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const yourTable = sequelize.define('yourTable', { // table name use it for Sequelize
    camelCase: { //camelCase name that you'll use with sequelize.
      field: 'under_score', //underscore name on yor database.
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    keyId: { //need to the same with association 
      field: 'key_id',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'your_table', // then name of the table on the db
    underscored: true,
  });

  yourTable.associate = (models) => {
    yourTable.belongsTo(models.otherTable, {   
      as: 'Something',   
      foreignKey: 'key_id', //put attention here and keyId above.
      onDelete: 'cascade'
    }); 
  }
}
```